# Protect entire website behind a login i.e. "Authorize" all Actions within all controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, authorization

title pretty much says it all.

I have a website which will only run behind a login so I want to ensure that nothing can be accessed unless you're logged in. This includes ActionResults, JsonResults etc...

Currently, I have `[Authorize]` all over my controllers which is quite tedious and **not very DRY** :)

**So can I protect the entire website with 1 magic line of code?** *(The login page will obviously need to be accessible)*

*Also, please note that I will still need to further protect some of the Actions to only be used by certain Users/Roles*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have multiple controllers, then make a AuthorizeController from which you inherit your controllers that must be protected. Just set the `[Authorize]` attribute to the AuthorizeController:

```
[Authorize]
public class AuthorizeController: Controller
{
}

public class HomeController : AuthorizeController
{
    ...
}

// don't inherit AccountController from AuthorizeController
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent stuff @Dave, this approach is even less **DRY** :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to secure an entire website, you could use a global filter:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
  {
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
  }
}
```

See here for more information http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2013/06/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Nevermind!** *I think I found it!*

Placing `[Authorize]` above the Controller class seems to protect all actions, and is further customisable on a per-action basis. **YES!**

```
[Authorize]
public class SomeController : Controller 
{
    // All logged in users
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        ...
    }

    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] // Only Admins
    public ActionResult Details() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```