# trying to secure website but also keep Home (index) page public MCV5 asp.net identity

Tags: security, ssl, model-view-controller, https, authorization

I have a site with a few pages and I implemented login and register.

then I implemented SSL and added redirects for anyone trying to access the site without HTTPS with the following code:

first I changed the project to only allow SSL HTTPS in project settings 
[image]

**GLOBAL ASAX**

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Request.Url.Scheme)
        {
            case "https":
                Response.AddHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=300");
                break;
            case "http":
                var path = "https://" + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                Response.AddHeader("Location", path);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**web.config**

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
          redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security"
          pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

When I first ran the project IIS installed a cert and it warned me I would also be allowed to access this site so when i run the project chrome (default browser) ALWAYS has access to the site no matter what the url looks like.
(first issue)

I'm trying to hit the site from IE or Firefox and IE for testing purposes and I can never hit index page if I use https, of course, it hits the page but I'm not logged in so I see that as an issue... I added

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["userid"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = Session["username"].ToString();
            return View();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

and still, I cannot access the site. I am very new to security please bear with me. what I would like as behavior is the site to be secure but users can hit index and register login etc.... but be denied when they try to hit other pages that require a login.

In summary
Chrome: always works (i see this as an issue)

IE/ FF:

- when using https works (i believe this to be an issue because I'm not logged in (when anonymous is removed).
- the page will not load if I use regular URL http://localhost:50499, but if I add allowannonymos it should work and it's not. (if i attach debugger it never hits the asax code but still denied)

Comment: Did authorization worked before changing the site to support SSL, i.e., was it redirecting user to login page if the user wasn' t logged in ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. If you're authorizing your users with OWIN and Identity then to secure your other controllers you would use something like the following

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult YourSecuredController()
{
if (Session["userid"] != null)
{
    ViewBag.UserName = Session["username"].ToString();
    return View();
}

return View();
}
```

Your public controllers wouldn't have the [Authorize] attribute in the header.
Also, if you want your website to be secure always with TLS 1.2 then you could add the following line to the Application_Start() method in Global.asax.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Yes I understand the authorize property, but i was hoping to add security to the whole site and ONLY have to allow public access to the home page. that way I don't have to keep adding [authorize].  I don't know security at all so I may be doing something completely wrong.

Comment: so let me add info and explain. I thought by changing the site to SSL it would only allow people to access the site via a secure connection, thus securing the site. my next thought was to allow the public go to to the index page and log in. thus making a secure connection and we would be done. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You would only need to Authorize the pages that require it. For example to update your personal data, check order status, etc. The https connection only ensures that no one can see your user' s info when he/ she edits his personal info or views order status while the info travels between web server and browser. In general it's good practice to have your whole site  https and Authorize only the pages that  need it and that deliver personal info.

Comment: On the other hand just yesterday we delivered a private company website. Only employees may use the site. So the first screen is the login screen and all pages have Authorize to prevent unauthorized access. Also the entire site is https to encrypt all trafic between web server and browser.

Comment: This link explains how to authorize an entire site without having to add Authorize to each controller. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092803/protect-entire-website-behind-a-login-i-e-authorize-all-actions-within-all-co